# How to align div and canvas horizontally to the grid

Tags: css, html5-canvas, alignment

Is there some useful techniques?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqoy7xjy/)

For text centering I  tried to  use this:

```
.wrapper div {
   position: relative;
   top: -8px;
}
```

To remove bottom canvas margin I tried to use this:

```
.wrapper canvas {
   margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

But I always try to avoid negative parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean vertically align? Like this?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.wrapper canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas width="32" height="32"></canvas>
  <div class="question">1234567890</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

```
canvas {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for horizontally design

```
<style> 
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:left;
}
.demo_class{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
} 
.demo_class .question{
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="demo_class">
    <canvas id="null" width="32" height="32" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="demo_class">
    <div class="question">1234567890</div>
</div>
```